# File upload input on mobile Safari

Tags: html, mobile-safari

I'm aware that it is now possible for users to upload files via HTML file inputs from their iPhones in mobile Safari.

In a desktop browser, if a file input already has a file selected, if you click the browse button, and then don't select a file, the file input "resets" to being blank.

It seems that in mobile Safari this behavior doesn't exist.  In other words, after selecting a file for a file input, there is no way to deselect the file and set the input back to blank.  Is this true, or am I missing something?